# Cargar datos RecycleView desde Json kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, recyclerview, kivy

estoy intentando cargar con kivy los siguientes datos que tengo en un json mediante un recyclerview que muestre un textinput con el valor del json y una label con el número de id que corresponde para que el usuario pueda cambiarlos dinamicamente y cambiar los nombres de ese json.
El archivo json es el siguiente:

```
{"1": "1", "3": "3", "4": "4", "5": "5", "6": "6", "7": "7", "11": "11", "12": "12", "101": "101", "102": "102", "103": "103"}
```

puede usarse como diccionario si se prefiere para el ejemplo, a nivel practico es igual.
Realmente el primer número hace referencia al id del centro y el segundo al nombre que se le asigna,
Creo que un formato mas correcto seria algo como:

```
[{'centro':'1','nombre': '1'}]
```

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
import json

#esta funcion nos devolvera el valor del json
def sacar_nombres():
    with open('data/centros.json') as f:
        places = json.load(f)
    return places

items = sacar_nombres()


class MyButton(GridLayout):

    def print_data(self,data):
        print(data)


KV = '''

<MyButton>:
    cols: 2
    TextInput:
    Label:
        text:'prueba'
RecycleView:
    data: []
    viewclass: 'MyButton'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        default_heigth: 100
        orientation: 'vertical'

'''


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        root = Builder.load_string(KV)
        root.data = [item for item in items]
        return root


Test().run()
```

La intencion es que cada input muestre el valor del nombre del json y cada label el valor del id, despuesa gregar un boton y guardar el nuevo valor en forma de Json. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase que actúa como fila, debe heredar de `kivy.uix.recycleview.views.RecycleDataViewBehavior`, hecho esto puedes usar el método `refresh_view_attrs` para asignar los valores.

Por otro lado la altura del `RecycleBoxLayout` debe ser la mínima para contener los items o será imposible el scrooll, te falta añadir los siguientes valores a éstas propiedades:

```
size_hint_y: None
height: self.minimum_height
```

Un ejemplo básico sería:

```
import json

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior


# esta funcion nos devolvera el valor del json
def sacar_nombres():
    with open('data/centros.json') as f:
        places = json.load(f)
    return places

items = sacar_nombres()


KV = '''

<CenterViewRow>:
    cols: 2
    labelid_text: ''
    entryname_text: ''
    TextInput:
        id: id_entryname
        text: root.entryname_text
    Label:
        id: id_labelid
        text: root.labelid_text

RecycleView:
    data: []
    viewclass: 'CenterViewRow'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        default_heigth: 100
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height

'''

class CenterViewRow(RecycleDataViewBehavior, GridLayout):
    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        self.entryname_text = data['entryname']
        self.labelid_text = data['labelid']
        return super().refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        root = Builder.load_string(KV)
        root.data= [
            {'entryname': item["id"],
             'labelid': item["centro"]}
             for item in items]

        print(root.data)
        return root


Test().run()
```

Como JSON de prueba:

> ```
> [{"id": "1", "nombre": "Centro A"},
>  {"id": "2", "nombre": "Centro B"},
>  {"id": "3", "nombre": "Centro C"}]
> ```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Genial es justo eso lo que buscaba.